# Reading data from a file; first packet is gibberish

Tags: c++, c, arrays, variable-assignment

I am trying to read 1244 bytes at a time from a file. Essentially, the idea is to segment the 100KB worth of data into packets. So the approach I am taking is, assigning all the data to an array and then creating an array of pointers which will contain starting positions to each of my packets. The pointer array contains values [0, 1244, 2488, and so on].

It works perfectly fine, except my first assignment is gibberish. k[0] and o[0] both come up with garbage while the remaining 79 values seem to be fine. Can anyone assist?

I realize the first argument to the fread command should be a pointer, but this worked also. Also, I need the pointers to the starting of each of my packets because I am doing other function calls (omitted from code) that format the packet properly with the appropriate headers.

It's been a while since I coded in c/c++ so any optimizations you could provide, would be much appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    FILE *data;
    int size; int i;
    int paySize = 1244;
    //int hdrSize = 256;

    data = fopen("text2.dat","r"); 

    //get data size
    fseek(data, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(data);
    rewind (data);

    char k[size]; //initializing memory location for all the data to be read in.

    fread(k, 1, size, data); //reading in data

    int temp = ceil(size/paySize);

    char * o[temp]; //array of pointers to beginning of each packet.

    int q = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i = i+paySize)
    {
        o[q] = &k[i];
        q++;
    }

    cout << o[0] << endl; //this outputs gibberish!
```

Comment: Because it is the address of k[i]? What you want might be *o[0]

Comment: What exactly do you expect with the line `cout << o[0] << endl;`? Do you expect it to print the first character in the file? Or the first packet as a whole?

Comment: I expect it to print the first 1244 bytes of the file. When i change the index value to 1 or anything else, it prints the whole 1244 bytes of information extracted from the input file.

Comment: I am asking this for confirmation; does `k[0]` also do not print what the first character on the file apparently is?

Comment: yes.. sorry, it's my mistake.... an index of k or o will not have 1244 bytes. i'll have to print in a for loop to get all 1244 bytes.

Comment: You've also got an off by one error: size/paySize is truncating integer division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cout << o[0] << endl;
```

prints an address to which this pointer points. To print value at this address use:

```
cout << *o[0] << endl;
```

Here:

```
char k[size];
char * o[temp];

o[q] = &k[i];
```

you assign to `o[]` pointers to characters, dereferencing such a pointer result in a single `char`.

Comment: yes.. i see your point. o is just an array of pointers of the beginning position of my packet. okay.. thanks.